# SpeechSynthesis, Web Speech API, remove the delay after speaking has finished and the onend property firing?

Tags: javascript, api, speech, speech-synthesis

I'm displaying an animated graphic whilst SpeechSynthesisUtterance is speaking. I'm using the onend property to detect when speaking has finished to remove the animated graphic. However there is a significant delay between the speaking finishing and the onend event firing, which means the animated graphic carries on playing for approximately 1 second even though the speaking has finished. Is it possible to remove this delay? The below code is a simple demonstration of the problem.

```
let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Approximately a second delay after utterance has finished and the onend event firing");
speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
utterance.onend = function () {
console.log("There is a delay before this message appears?");
```

}

Comment: You can use `boundary` events and check the `charIndex` on the event. If it is at a location of the penultimate word in the utterance, update your graphic then instead of `onend`.

Comment: @morganney - many thanks for the comment. I've tried your solution and it works perfectly :)

Comment: Great, I've added an answer that demonstrates an example approach. Please accept it as the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `end` event, here is an example of how you can use the [`boundary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/boundary_event) event to remove something from the DOM based on the `evt.charIndex` of the utterance being spoken.

This removes the graphic after the penultimate word finishes speaking:

```js
function getPenultimateWordEndingIndex(text) {
  const words = text.split(' ').filter(Boolean)

  // Can use words.slice(-1, -1)[0] for better browser support
  return text.lastIndexOf(words.at(-1))
}

const text = 'This image should be removed after hearing the word "event" spoken.'
const index = getPenultimateWordEndingIndex(text)
const graphic = document.getElementById('graphic')
const utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text)

utter.addEventListener('boundary', evt => {
  if (evt.charIndex >= index) {
    graphic.remove()
  }
})

document.getElementById('speak').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(utter)
})
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="100" id="graphic" />
<p>This image should be removed after hearing the word "event" spoken. (accept chrome/android which doesn't fire boundary events)</p>
<button id="speak">speak</button>
```